# Google maps spatial reference system

Tags: google-maps, spatial, geotools

What is Google map's spatial reference system using when you enter a lat, long into the maps search bar?

I've found hints that it might be WGS84 but after converting to that coordinate system, nothing shows up when i paste the coordinates into the google maps search box.

I am converting from GDA MGA 56.

Sample:

- Input MGA56 coords: 336301, 6253363
- Expected WGS86 coords: -33.8473340793201, 151.230631835944
- I get: 16834916.928327594 -4008321.1020318186

Spatial coord systems:

- EPSG:28356 for MGA56
- EPSG:900913 for WGS86 (google maps)

I am using geotools to do the transform:

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crsMga56 = CRS.parseWKT(mga56);
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crsGmaps = CRS.parseWKT(gmaps);

    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(336301, 6253363);
    Point point = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(coordinate);

    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(crsMga56, crsGmaps);
    Geometry geometry = JTS.transform(point, transform);
```

I know the transform is not correct, as when i use an online tool it gives me the correct coords. http://www.environment.gov.au/cgi-bin/transform/mga2geo_gda.pl?east=336301&north=6253363&zone=56

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding "nothing shows up"? What coordinate system are you converting *from*?

Comment: I guess that's the expected result, since Australia contains a whole lot of nothing. :)

Comment: More seriously, could you also give an example of your input coordinates, and your converted WGS84 coordinates? Google Maps should show *something* for any valid geographic coordinate, even if it's outback or ocean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google uses a spherical mercator projection based on WGS84. There's a [writeup](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) on the OpenLayers website.

Answer (score 1):

If it is any use, we found GeoTools were changing the JVM so that lat & long were the opposite way around (i.e. 151,-33), which might explain why you are getting out of bounds {151 > 90}) it was a nightmare to find