# State plane to lat long conversion

Tags: java, gis, latitude-longitude

I am looking to create an algorithm that converts datum in state plane coordinate system (1983) to lat long.  I realize that ever state has there own zone and measurement system(meters, international feet, survey feet).  Does anyone know of a existing library for this type of conversion?  I have found an old FORTRAN program, http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/SPCS83/ ,
however I would prefer to avoid the pain of translating this to java if at all possible.

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676958/coordinate-transform) might be of good help for you :)

Comment: You can use `PROJ.4` or `GDAL` library (which uses PROJ.4 library) to perform valid coordinate transformation conversion between two map projections. Although `GDAL` library is usually used with geo-referenced maps, you can actually use it with maps.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google turned up this candidate, which looks like it's on the right lines - does it help?

[Map Projecton Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/)